# Do function when select in autocomplete(Jquery)

Tags: jquery, function, autocomplete

I'm using the autocomplete of Jquery: [reference](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

I would like to do a function which looks like this:

```
var searchTerms = getSearch();
        doSearch(searchTerms);
```

It is related to the value of an input, so it does `doSearch` based on the value of input. I want to do this function when coming down in the autocomplete li. I tried:

```
select: function(e, ui){
       $(input).autocomplete('search', ui.item.value);
```

Which seems to work when clicking an item in the list, but I want it to work when coming down in the list. What do I have to change? I have read the docs(link) and tried many things with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

you can bind a focus event handler to the `li`

```
$(document).delegate("li","focus",function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$(input).autocomplete('search', $(this).text()); //dont know what the input is so included "as it is"
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me (Im trying to figure out why..)

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work using the 'selected' Class:

```
$(input).bind("keyup", function() {

var text = $(".ui-state-hover").text();
     doSearch(text); 

});
```